# codeigniter requete get with two parameters

Tags: sql, codeigniter, api

i want to get the nearby places from my current location (latitude,longitude)

i make this method in my controller

```
 function etablissement_get(){if(!$this->get('latitude','longitude')){
         $this->response(NULL, 400);
    }
    $data = array('etablissements:',$this->Etablissement_model->get_relation_by_etablissement($this->get('latitude','longitude')));

     if($data)
    {
        $this->response($data, 200);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->response(array('error' => 'Entity could not be found'), 404);
    }}
```

and this method in my model

```
public function get_relation_by_etablissement($latitude,$longitude)
{
  $this->db->select(' m.ref_relation,m.image,mylocation.latitude as "latitude my location",mylocation.longitude as "longitude my location", near.latitude as "latitude nearby me",near.longitude as "longitude near by me",near.title as "title nearby me",near.actif as"state nearby me",near.adresse as "adresse nearby me",near.rate as"rate nearby me"');
    $this->db->from('relations M');

    $this->db->join('etablissement mylocation', ' m.ref_local=mylocation.id ');
    $this->db->join('etablissement near', ' m.ref_relation=near.id ');

    $this->db->where('mylocation.latitude',$latitude, 'mylocation.longitude',$longitude);



          $query=$this->db->get();
          echo $this->db->last_query();
return $query->result();}
```

i get the result but with some warning. when i var_dump my query there is only one parameter in argument ( latitude=55.978456) without longitude. how to make it work with the two parameters

Answer (score 0):

Should be like that:

```
if(!$this->get('latitude') || !$this->get('longitude'))
{
     $this->response(NULL, 400);
}
```

Comment: sorry but it doesn't change anything

Comment: @user3921905 What you get when you dump `$this->get('latitude')` and `$this->get('longitude')` data?

Comment: WHERE mylocation.latitude = '48.8633216' AND mylocation.longitude IS NULL["etablissements:",[]]

Comment: What's your query/url?

Comment: http://localhost:9090/CodeIgniter/index.php/api/etablissements/etablissement/latitude/48.8633216/longitude/2.337843399999997

Comment: the requete is correct but the prob is in second parameter he said Missing argument 2 for Etablissement_model

Comment: now it work thank you i just change this : $data = array('etablissements:',$this->Etablissement_model->get_relation_by_etablissement($this->get('latitude'),$this->get('longitude')));

Answer (score -1):

$this->db->where('mylocation.latitude',$latitude);
$this->db->where('mylocation.longitude',$longitude);

It will treat it as "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE `mylocation.latitude` = $latitude AND `mylocation.longitude` = $longitude"

Comment: sorry i tried it before but it doesn't work this is the result: 
WHERE `mylocation`.`latitude` =  '48.8633216'
AND `mylocation`.`longitude` IS NULL["etablissements:",[]]

Comment: then you can do
$this->db->where('mylocation.latitude',$latitude);
$this->db->or_where('mylocation.longitude',$longitude);

Comment: i want it to be and not or. i tried. it's the same error always the longitude is null